# please help me to find the error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, opencv

following code is for Detecting lines with Hough transform.But this code doesn't work properly.It says "cannot open pic1.png".Can you please check this code and tell me what is wrong with this code.Please help me. I am using openCV 2.3 library and visual studio 2010.Thank you.

```
  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
  #include"cv.h"
  #include"cxcore.h"
  #include"stdafx.h"

  #include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void help()
{
cout << "\nThis program demonstrates line finding with the Hough transform.\n"
        "Usage:\n"
        "./houghlines <image_name>, Default is pic1.png\n" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
const char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "pic1.png";

Mat src = imread(filename, 0);
if(src.empty())
{
    help();
    cout << "can not open " << filename << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat dst, cdst;
Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

#if 0
vector<Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );

for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
    Point pt1, pt2;
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
    pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
    pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
    pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
    line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
}
#else
vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
}
#endif
imshow("source", src);
imshow("detected lines", cdst);

waitKey();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well? Do you have a `pic1.png` file in that same directory?

Comment: @Mat - probably a misunderstanding about where the program runs vs where the file lives

Comment: Don't understand the down votes here. It is a straightforward question with a straightforward answer. Please suggest the reason for downvoting so the question can be improved.

Comment: yes, pic1.png file is in the same directory.

Comment: agree with you @daramarak. i think these people are too full of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for `pic1.png` in the same directory that the executable is running from.

You either need to copy the image to the same directory or enter the path (either full or relative) to the image file.

Answer (score -1):

Mat src = imread("pic1.png", 0); // put the image pic1.png at the current directory.

Mat src = imread("C://...", 0); // at some other directory like @ChrisF stated.

Comment: What is this? Is this supposed to be code? What's the `>>` operator doing there? Were you trying to write a comment (`//`)?

Comment: @CodyGray: // is not a comment and >> that is not a operator there in the above mentioned lines.

Comment: yes , i have put the image (pic1.png)at the same directory.but i doesn't work.

Comment: is this the problem?                                              const char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "pic1.png";                                    can you explain this code ??

Comment: That line means that if when you run the program you provide a filename (e.g. `progName myImage.png`), use the provided name, but otherwise default to pic1.png.

Comment: sorry.my mistakes. tend to use >> as explanation for the text before.